# Jquery variable value to use Title of HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to assign values which I have in Jquery variable to Title of  elements?

E.g.
var params will have value Assigned, Assignee etc.

How can I set the title of  element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use title attribute

Using jQuery object

```
$('#yourElement').attr('title', varibleval);
```

Using javascript DOM object

```
$('#yourElement')[0].title = varibleval;
```

Comment: Or .prop("title",variable)

Comment: That is the original Dom object

Comment: Keep in mind that the `title` attribute is reserved for tooltips and you should use `data-title` instead to adhere to current conventions.